# Can anyone help me with the playerctl output?

Tags: linux, bash

There is program called "playerctl" in linux which is used get metadata and status of the playing music.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(echo -n $(playerctl status)) == "Playing" ]; then
    echo " play "
elif [ $(echo -n $(playerctl status)) == "Paused" ]; then
    echo " pause "
elif [ $(echo -n $(playerctl status 2>/dev/null)) == "No players found" ]; then
    echo " not found "
else
    echo "other"
fi
```

The output should either of the four echo statements.
But I am getting "No players found"

Comment: What do you get if you run `playerctl status`?

Comment: when playing music - Playing

Comment: when music paused - Paused

Comment: when nothing is playing - No players found

Comment: First try to correct the other problems by checking in [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net). The other problem could arise because the string doesn't match 100% (spaces etc). Try using `=~`, e.g. `d=" play "; if [[ "${d}" =~ "play" ]];then echo "OK" ;fi`. Also check if `d="$(echo -n "$(playerctl status)")"` assigns a string.

Comment: Try
`status="$(palyerctl status 2> /dev/null)"` and use `$status` in your if-then-else